# Preserve Sorting While Merging Two Observables

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, system.reactive

I want to merge 2 observables and keep the order (probably based on a selector). I also want to put back-pressure on source of the observable.

So the selector would choose one of the items to push on through the observable and the other item would wait for another item to come to compare too.

Src1, Src2, and Result are all of type `IObservable<T>`.

```
Src1: { 1,3,6,8,9,10 }
Src2: { 2,4,5,7,11,12 }
Result: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12

Timeline:
Src1:    -1---3----6------8----9-10
Src2:    --2-----4---5-7----11---------12
Result:  --1--2--3-4-5-6--7-8--9-10-11-12
```

1. In the example above, src1 emits '1' and is blocked until src2 emits
   it's first item, '2'.
2. A selector, which selects the smallest item, is applied which
   selects the item from src1.
3. Src2 now waits for the next item (from src1) to compare with its
   current item ('2').
4. When src1 emits the next item, '3', the selection is ran again, this
   time selecting the item from src2.
5. This repeats until one of the observables completes. Then, the remaining observable pushes items until it completes.

Is this possible to achieve with the existing .net Rx methods?

EDIT: Note the 2 source observables are guaranteed to be in order.

Example Test:

```
var source1 = new List<int>() { 1, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 14 }.AsEnumerable();
var source2 = new List<int>() { 2, 3, 5, 9, 11, 12, 13, 15 }.AsEnumerable();

var src1 = source1.ToObservable();
var src2 = source2.ToObservable();

var res = src1.SortedMerge(src2, (a, b) =>
    {
       if (a <= b)
           return a;
       else
           return b;
    });

res.Subscribe((x) => Console.Write($"{x}, "));
```

DesiredResult: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15

Comment: How are you merging observables? Please give your code.
Because [Merge](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html) operator doesn't wait for sources sequentially

Comment: @MohammadOmidvar - That's what he's asking for.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't get correctly. So by "the existing .net Rx methods", do you mean built-in operators or the possibility at all? @msauce4. Because it is possible to write a subject able to do this.

Comment: @MohammadOmidvar I'm looking to do it with any combination of the built-in operators, but if that's not possible I'm curious about writing a subject. Say we ignore the back-pressure issue, can it be done then? It's somewhat similar to this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50298555/rx-net-combine-observables-in-order , question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fun to do. Had to tweak the algorithm a bit. It could be further improved.

Assumptions:

1. There are two streams, `streamA`, `streamB` of the common type `T`.
2. The two streams are separately sorted such that `streamA[i] < streamA[i+1]` and `streamB[i] < stream[i+1]`.
3. You cannot assume any relationship between `streamA[i]` and `streamB[i]`.
4. Streams A & B are discreet: The same element won't emit from both. If this happens, I'm throwing `NotImplementedException`. *This case is easily handled, but I wanted to avoid ambiguity.*
5. There is a function `min` for type `T`.
6. No assumptions are made regarding relative velocity of the two streams, but if one is consistently faster than the other, backpressure will be a problem.

Here's the algorithm I used:

- Let there be two queues, `qA` and `qB`.
- When you get an item from `streamA`, enqueue it into `qA`.
- When you get an item from `streamB`, enqueue it into `qB`.
- While there is an item in **both** `qA` and `qB`, compare the top items of the two queues. Remove and emit the min of those two. If both queues are still non-empty, repeat.
- If either `streamA` or `streamB` completes, dump the contents of the queues and terminate. **Note**: *This is admittedly lazy, and should probably change to dump, then continue returning the non-completed observable*.

Here's the code:

```
public static IObservable<T> SortedMerge<T>(this IObservable<T> source, IObservable<T> other)
{
    return SortedMerge(source, other, (a, b) => Enumerable.Min(new[] { a, b}));
}

public static IObservable<T> SortedMerge<T>(this IObservable<T> source, IObservable<T> other, Func<T, T, T> min)
{
    return source
        .Select(i => (key: 1, value: i)).Materialize()
        .Merge(other.Select(i => (key: 2, value: i)).Materialize())
        .Scan((qA: ImmutableQueue<T>.Empty, qB: ImmutableQueue<T>.Empty, exception: (Exception)null, outputMessages: new List<T>()), 
            (state, message) =>
        {
            if (message.Kind == NotificationKind.OnNext)
            {
                var key = message.Value.key;
                var value = message.Value.value;
                var qA = state.qA;
                var qB = state.qB;
                if (key == 1)
                    qA = qA.Enqueue(value);
                else
                    qB = qB.Enqueue(value);
                var output = new List<T>();
                while(!qA.IsEmpty && !qB.IsEmpty)
                {
                    var aVal = qA.Peek();
                    var bVal = qB.Peek();
                    var minVal = min(aVal, bVal);
                    if(aVal.Equals(minVal) && bVal.Equals(minVal))
                        throw new NotImplementedException();

                    if(aVal.Equals(minVal))
                    {
                        output.Add(aVal);
                        qA = qA.Dequeue();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        output.Add(bVal);
                        qB = qB.Dequeue();
                    }
                }
                return (qA, qB, null, output);
            }
            else if (message.Kind == NotificationKind.OnError)
            {
                return (state.qA, state.qB, message.Exception, new List<T>());
            }
            else //message.Kind == NotificationKind.OnCompleted
            {
                var output = state.qA.Concat(state.qB).ToList();
                return (ImmutableQueue<T>.Empty, ImmutableQueue<T>.Empty, null, output);
            }
        })
        .Publish(tuples => Observable.Merge(
            tuples
                .Where(t => t.outputMessages.Any() && (!t.qA.IsEmpty || !t.qB.IsEmpty))
                .SelectMany(t => t.outputMessages
                    .Select(v => Notification.CreateOnNext<T>(v))
                    .ToObservable()
            ),
            tuples
                .Where(t => t.outputMessages.Any() && t.qA.IsEmpty && t.qB.IsEmpty)
                .SelectMany(t => t.outputMessages
                    .Select(v => Notification.CreateOnNext<T>(v))
                    .ToObservable()
                    .Concat(Observable.Return(Notification.CreateOnCompleted<T>()))
            ),
            tuples
                .Where(t => t.exception != null)
                .Select(t => Notification.CreateOnError<T>(t.exception))
        ))
        .Dematerialize();
```

`ImmutableQueue` comes from `System.Collections.Immutable`. `Scan` is required to keep track of state. Materialization is required because of the `OnCompleted` handling. This is admittedly a complicated solution, but I'm not sure there's a cleaner Rx-centric way.

Let me know if there's something you want more clarification about.

Comment: I added an example test to the question. Running your method yields this result: "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 7, 9, 10, 11, 13, 12, 14,".  8 and 13 is in the wrong place, and 15 doesn't appear to have gotten dumped. Any idea why?

Comment: Also, what drives the necessity of the Materialize() calls?

Comment: Changing the observable formation to ToObservable(NewThreadScheduler.Default) results in the test returning expected results.